# Polynomial multiplication and division in $2^{128}$

Tags: implementation

I want to multiply and divide polynomials, and implement the extended Euclidean algorithm for polynomial greatest common divisors, over a Galois Field of size $2^{128}$. Moreover, I want to use the previous algorithms on an 8-bit microcontroller (ATMega128). Where can I find relevant libraries in C or Assembly? Ι would prefer C, if the implementation is not too inefficient. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The [RELIC](http://code.google.com/p/relic-toolkit/) library has support for binary fields. Check the functions fb_inv_exgcd for inversion and fb_mul_lodah (which calls fb_muln_low and fb_rdcn_low) for multiplication. There is even a ATMega128 backend written in assembly, though it does not support 128-bit fields (but should give you a head start if you need to write it).

You will need to make a few adjustments in order to isolate the multiplication code, but it shouldn't be too hard. Or you can simply use the library as is.

(Disclosure: I'm one of its developers)